# How to read the latest image in a folder using python?

Tags: image, python-2.7, image-processing

I have to read the latest image in a folder using python. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide more background information on what your trying to do, what you have tried so far etc.

Comment: Iceman the webcam takes pic every 5 minutes...and writes it into a folder..So I have to read the latest image from that folder and detect face in the image. Face detection part is done..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another similar way, with some pragmatic (non-foolproof) image validation added:

```
import os

def get_latest_image(dirpath, valid_extensions=('jpg','jpeg','png')):
    """
    Get the latest image file in the given directory
    """

    # get filepaths of all files and dirs in the given dir
    valid_files = [os.path.join(dirpath, filename) for filename in os.listdir(dirpath)]
    # filter out directories, no-extension, and wrong extension files
    valid_files = [f for f in valid_files if '.' in f and \
        f.rsplit('.',1)[-1] in valid_extensions and os.path.isfile(f)]

    if not valid_files:
        raise ValueError("No valid images in %s" % dirpath)

    return max(valid_files, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Answer (score 2):

Walk over the filenames, [get their modification time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=getmtime#os.path.getmtime) and keep track of the latest modification time you found:

```
import os
import glob

ts = 0
found = None
for file_name in glob.glob('/path/to/your/interesting/directory/*'):
    fts = os.path.getmtime(file_name)
    if fts > ts:
        ts = fts
        found = file_name

print(found)
```

Comment: Thanks Anthon..I want the path to be a different folder not where the code exists...for this should I set the path to that folder in which I have to check the image?

Comment: @pradeepln4 Just change the argument to glob: `glob.glob('/your/full/path/with/expandable/parts/*')`  You can have `*` (multiple characters) and `?` (single character) that expand. You can have multiple patterns: `'/your/*/path/abc??.png'`

Comment: Simple and great solution Anthon. Thx.